# What is the use for uniform<T>? What's the difference between uniform buffer can be passed by setVertexBytes()?

Tags: metal

In Metal Shading Language Specification, Behavior of Uniform Type:

> If a variable is of the uniform type, and the variable does not have the same value for all threads executing the kernel or graphics function, then the behavior is undefined.

```
uniform<float> bar[10]; // elements stored in bar array are uniform
```

My question is what is use for `uniform<T>`  in this context?  I know some uniforms such as transformation information can be passed to shader by `setVertexBytes()` as uniform.  In what kind of situations, do you find `uniform<T>` useful?

```
struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
};

struct Uniforms {
    float4x4 transform;
};

vertex VertexOut my_vertex(
    const device VertexIn * vertices [[buffer(0)]],
    constant Uniforms & uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
    uint vid [[vertex_id]]
) {
…
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Keep reading: the document outlines its use. Pg 46. of the MSL Specification version 2.3 effectively says that if you know a (runtime) value will be the same across threads, you can mark that value as such by using the `uniform<T>` template. This can allow the texture hardware to optimize texture samples/reads/writes etc. It also mentions that control flow with uniforms can be more efficient. A constant buffer passed through device memory is different: it is merely a buffer that is read-only (usually for uniforms). Certain optimizations can be made in that case as well(e.g., buffer preloading)

Comment: I have never used `uniform<T>` yet, but I can imagine it is useful